# Android with Eclipse - Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched?

Tags: android, eclipse

When I try to run the Hello World app with Eclipse, the Console shows "Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...", but even if I wait for half an hour, nothing happens except for the emulator showing the "Android"-logo on a black background.
The same happens when I try to start the emulator directly via AVD Manager. The PATH variable is set correctly, I've installed the newest versions of both eclipse and the Android SDK.

What could possibly be the reason for this to happen?

Thanks!

Comment: Nov. 2013, Android dev is still painful !! need hours on google to find why the simplest HelloWorld sample doesn't work AS IT...

Comment: @erwin Don't use Google samples or libraries.  They just barf out partially working stuff and never update it or its docs.  3rd party stuff is much better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem is in SD Card follow this steps,

1) Select **Window** option from **eclipse menubar**

2) Goto **AVD Manager** and select the **emulator** (which got probs after started).

3) After selecting **Emulator**, click **Edit** button which is on your right hand side of the AVD Manager

4) Goto **SD Card Size** give `128` and then click '**Edit AVD**' option down

5) And **restart** your emulator

Answer (score 5):

It worked for me when I selected 'Use Host GPU' option under 'Emulation Options:'.

You can find the option under Edit window of the virtual device.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try the path it can be the issue.

My advice - if you having an android phone.. please usb debug it and Debug your application on your phone. You will feel relieved from the long durations of the emulator to

Answer (score 2):

"Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched.."

I found that the keyword here is 'wait'. I gave up waiting many times on a slower laptop. When I switched to a faster desktop and left it alone for a good while the emulator eventually booted up. Think how long it takes your android device to boot up, then consider that is running as an emulated ARM processor + the rest of the SoC architecture, on just 1 core of your actual real life x86 processor.

Also, I was giving the SD card a GB or so "just in case", this just slowed it down even more as it had to allocate this space on the slow laptop hard drive before it even began booting the emulator.

Just being a little patient worked for me, and once the emulator is up and running don't close it! You can simply close the program you are testing on the virtual device and then re-upload/install with eclipse again and again as you test your code.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the path is set correctly? The path variable should be set to both SDKHOME/tools and SDKHOME/platform-tools, where SDKHOME is your android sdk home folder.

Most of the time, people forget this and just set the path to /platform-tools or the other one only.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility may be that your computer is running out of disk space.

Answer (score 0):

Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...

I did not run my emulator then I start to run my app. But my emulator stayed black screen and there are console ms "Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...".

I stop my app then I setup my emulator before I run my app. It run perfect.

Run your emulator first from Window -> AVD Manager -> (select your emulator)Start

Done.